# Sieve of Eratosthenes to print prime numbers in a given range

Tags: java, sieve-of-eratosthenes

This is my implementation for Sieve of Eratosthenes in Java.Please let me know how can I further improve my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 2; i <= 120; i++) {
        numbers.add(i);
    }

    int digit = 2;
    while (digit <= numbers.size()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {

            if (numbers.get(i) != digit && numbers.get(i) % digit == 0) {
                numbers.remove(i);
                i--;

            }

        }
        digit++;
    }

    for (int a : numbers)
        System.out.println(a);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is NO Sieve of Eratosthenes. Can you see *any division* [in this algorithm description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Algorithm_description)???

What you're doing is trial division. Worsened by

- even checking things like "does 100 divide 2?"
- using a list which does not allow efficient removal
- using `Integer` rather than `int`

The complexity is something like \$O(n^3)\$ as there are 3 nested loops: 2 in your code and 1 in `numbers.remove`.

The complexity should be \$O(n^\frac32)\$ which comes from using an "indicator array"(*) and iterating up to \$\sqrt n\$ only.

(*) It tracks for each int the information if it's a prime or not. It can be implemented e.g. as a `boolean[]` or a `BitSet`. The point is that all you need is an indexed access, no search, no elements shifting....